# Is ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit MaskedEdit Broken in IE9?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax, internet-explorer-9, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've just found that an ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit [`MaskedEditExtender`](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) isn't working in one of my old web applications.

My usage:

```
<asp:TextBox
    ID="TextBoxProductPrice"
    runat="server"
    CssClass="TextBoxProductPrice" />
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender
    ID="MaskedEditExtenderTextBoxProductPrice"
    runat="server"
    TargetControlID="TextBoxProductPrice"
    Mask="9,999.99"
    MaskType="Number"
    MessageValidatorTip="False"
    OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"
    OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
    InputDirection="RightToLeft"
    AcceptNegative="None"
    DisplayMoney="Left" />
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditValidator
    ID="MaskedEditValidatorTextBoxProductPrice"
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="TextBoxProductPrice"
    ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtenderTextBoxProductPrice"
    Display="Dynamic"
    IsValidEmpty="False"
    EmptyValueMessage="Price is required"
    InvalidValueMessage="Price is invalid"
    MinimumValue= "0.01"
    MinimumValueMessage="Price is too small"
    MaximumValue="9999.99" 
    MaximumValueMessage="Price is too large" />
```

There is no error. It just doesn't accept keystrokes correctly.

It fails with both Internet Explorer 9 and Chrome 12 on Windows 7.

It works correctly with Internet Explorer 6 on Windows XP.

Is the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit incompatible with modern browsers?

Comment: Is there an option to use jQuery? I have so many compatability issues with ajaxControl ToolKit over the years.  I dont use it any more  you could try this http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: @feanz I think that you're right. Microsoft's toolkit is too troublesome. There are several jQuery money plugins available. http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/money

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit to the [newest available version](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/). It now functions.

But, I think that the behavior seems to be slightly different than before. I added the text *"Tip: Type '.' to switch"* as instruction. I expect that users will still have trouble using this.

See the issues at the [Ajax Control Toolkit sample site](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx).

There are several [jQuery money plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/money) available. Any of those might provide a more usable solution.